# ServiceStack Self Hosting Redirect any 404 for SPA (Url Rewrite)

Tags: angularjs, servicestack

I'm using self hosting servicestack for a single page application with mvc and razor. On the same apphost i serve some api. The problem is i need some a 404 redirect to the main path "/" to get html5 mode running in AngularJS. I've tried:

`DefaultRedirectPath = "/"`
`this.GlobalHtmlErrorHttpHandler = new RazorHandler("/");`

How can i get any 404 request to the main page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a [Fallback Route](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fallback-route) with a wildcard for this which will let you handle unknown server routes in your Service in order to return the default page so routing can be handled in the client app, e.g:

```
[FallbackRoute("/{PathInfo*}")]
public class FallbackForClientRoutes
{
    public string PathInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(FallbackForClientRoutes request)
    {
        return new HttpResult {
            View = "/default.cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

This is [also the strategy](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks/blob/a5ec943e6b21dda733be26a566a0ba185df31ae2/src/TechStacks/TechStacks.ServiceInterface/ClientRoutesService.cs#L41) used by the [techstacks.io](http://techstacks.io) AngularJS Single Page App which also supports server-generated pages with [techstacks.io/?html=server](http://techstacks.io/?html=server).

Comment: Do we need to do anything in addition to this if we are using .net core? I tried just to create service like this, but it's not capturing anything, it's just returning 404 for url generated with ServiceStack Angular SPA template.

Comment: @ShP Nope, this is what all of [ServiceStack’s .NET Core’s SPA templates](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates) use to return the home page for SPA routes so it uses the SPA fx client routes.

Comment: Yeah that was the correct code, however, we need to make sure that`GetRouteAttributes` is not affecting this path (which was my case). So I had to use something like this: ```public override RouteAttribute[] GetRouteAttributes(Type requestType)
{
  var routes = base.GetRouteAttributes(requestType);
  routes.Where(r=>!(r.Path.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("/{PATH*}"))).Each(x => x.Path = "/API" + x.Path);
  return routes;
}```